# How to scroll section with full height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, fullpage.js

I have this demo [click](https://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Dxtyu/141/)

How to scroll section in demo with full height like a fullPage.js?
[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Dxtyu/141/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

    //smoothscroll
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).off("scroll");

        $('a').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        })
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var target = this.hash,
            menu = target;
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
        }, 500, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
            $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: So where is the problem ?

Comment: I want the above demo to work as fullPage.js, in the scrolling section to slide to the whole can not be moved into the center section